# Consistent numbering of linguex-examples across chapters

Tags: numbering, external-files, linguistics, linguex

I am using a template for my thesis, which imports separate .tex files for each chapter into the main.tex.

Using linguex, my examples start to renumber from (1) each chapter and I cannot seem to resolve this with \setcounter. Any ideas on what could be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude the `ExNo` counter from the reset list of `chapter`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{linguex}

\counterwithout{ExNo}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{first}

\ex. This is the first level of embedding
    \a. This is the second level
    \b. This is still the second level, but:
        \a. This is the third level
        \b. This is not the end.
        \b. This is the end

\chapter{second}

\ex. This is the first level of embedding
    \a. This is the second level
    \b. This is still the second level, but:
        \a. This is the third level
        \b. This is not the end.
        \b. This is the end

\end{document}
```

[image]